# Getting xunit to supply app.config in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, configurationmanager

I'm trying to get SpecFlow to run under .NET core, using xunit as the test runner. As part of the operation of the test, SpecFlow loads its configuration with a call to `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("specFlow")`.

The project references the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` package to enable this call under .NET Core, however it seems to want to load configuration from my NuGet cache.

> .nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform.testhost\15.3.0\lib\netstandard1.5\testhost.dll.config

As a result, the SpecFlow configuration section is not found and it falls back to trying to load an NUnit component (which naturally fails).

Is there a way to get the `ConfigurationManager` to pick up configuration from a different location, so calls to `GetSection` will return the expected configuration values?